# Where are doGet()/doPost() methods in HttpServlet class linked to service() method of superclass GenericServlet ?

Tags: servlets, service

The image underneath describes the servlet architecture.

[Servlet Architecture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KViDu.jpg)

It says that the **HttpServlet** class need not implement the service() method as its being taken care by **GenericServlet** class. The **HttpServlet** class must only implement the doGet() and doPost() methods.

**Doubt**

In this diagram hierarchy, where are the signatures of doGet() and doPost() present, ie, how implementation of doGet()/doPost() is triggering a call to service() in GenericServlet class, because even abstract signatures of doGet() and doPost() are absent in GenericServlet class.

**Question**

I have a belief there is a nested call to these methods in service() method of superclass GenericServlet. Is this correct perception or it works in some other way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your suspicion is almost correct, the calls to `doGet()`, `doPost()` and the other do-methods are in the `HttpServlet` class, which extends `GenericServlet`. This is taken from version 3.1 of the Servlet API jar (see [the source code starting at line 677](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/javax/servlet/javax.servlet-api/3.1.0/javax/servlet/http/HttpServlet.java?av=f)):

```
protected void service(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp)
    throws ServletException, IOException
{
    String method = req.getMethod();

    if (method.equals(METHOD_GET)) {
        long lastModified = getLastModified(req);
        if (lastModified == -1) {
            // servlet doesn't support if-modified-since, no reason
            // to go through further expensive logic
            doGet(req, resp);
        } else {
            long ifModifiedSince = req.getDateHeader(HEADER_IFMODSINCE);
            if (ifModifiedSince < lastModified) {
                // If the servlet mod time is later, call doGet()
                // Round down to the nearest second for a proper compare
                // A ifModifiedSince of -1 will always be less
                maybeSetLastModified(resp, lastModified);
                doGet(req, resp);
            } else {
                resp.setStatus(HttpServletResponse.SC_NOT_MODIFIED);
            }
        }

    } else if (method.equals(METHOD_HEAD)) {
        long lastModified = getLastModified(req);
        maybeSetLastModified(resp, lastModified);
        doHead(req, resp);

    } else if (method.equals(METHOD_POST)) {
        doPost(req, resp);

    } else if (method.equals(METHOD_PUT)) {
        doPut(req, resp);

    } else if (method.equals(METHOD_DELETE)) {
        doDelete(req, resp);

    } else if (method.equals(METHOD_OPTIONS)) {
        doOptions(req,resp);

    } else if (method.equals(METHOD_TRACE)) {
        doTrace(req,resp);

    } else {
        //
        // Note that this means NO servlet supports whatever
        // method was requested, anywhere on this server.
        //

        String errMsg = lStrings.getString("http.method_not_implemented");
        Object[] errArgs = new Object[1];
        errArgs[0] = method;
        errMsg = MessageFormat.format(errMsg, errArgs);

        resp.sendError(HttpServletResponse.SC_NOT_IMPLEMENTED, errMsg);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for revealing the treasure of information as well :)